# Apache Fallback instead of add_rewrite_rule

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, fallback

My requirement is to do SEO Friendly URL for an existing site in Wordpress.

For example,

```
Current URL: http://localhost/test/?pid=19971
that is the page "test" is rendering the data from some custom plugin. 

My new SEO URL : http://localhost/brand/sub_category/product_name
Here, Brand, Sub_category and product_name is fetched from the pid..
```

I am populating the data using the following rewrite rule from functions.php,

```
add_rewrite_rule(MY_DYNAMICALLY_POPULATED_URL.'$ page-test.php?brand='.$brand_name.'&sub='.$sub_category.'&pname='.$product_name.' [L]', 'top');
```

In this code, the `page-test.php` is placed in the root directory and the data is rendered from that file by passing the `brand_name`, `sub_category` and `productname` to fetch the **pid**. So based on the **pid** each product page is rendered.

This code is working fine for me, When I save the data automatically the data is written in `.htaccess` and page is rendering with the new SEO URL.

But when my client needs it to do it by FALLBACK in Apache instead of `add_rewrite_rule` due to some load balancing issue.

So can anyone help me how to do the same with `Fallback resource`.

Comment: Finally using the "page_rewrite_rules" filter I have done it without writing it to .htaccess file.

Comment: Duplicate Posting; Moderator notified. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141921/apache-fallback-instead-of-add-rewrite-rule - Should be cleaned up soon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was asked and answered on WordPress SE http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141921/apache-fallback-instead-of-add-rewrite-rule

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fixed my issue.

```
function my_query_vars($vars)
{
$my_vars = array( 'PARAMETERS' );
return array_merge($my_vars, $vars);
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');


function my_rewrite_rules($rules)
{
global $wp_rewrite;
$my_page = 'PAGESLUG';
$my_rule = array( 'URL/?' => 'index.php?pagename=' . $my_page . '&school_type=$matches[1]' );
return array_merge($my_rule, $rules);
}
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules');
```